# Always overwrite, don't ask

Tags: kubuntu, sftp, dolphin

When accessing a remote network directory with the help of Dolphin I often want to edit files and save. Each and every time it kindly reminds me this file already exists and requires I click through 2 dialog boxes to confirm I want to upload and overwrite the file.

Is there a setting to dangerously force overwriting pre-existing files somewhere within Dolphin? I don't see it within the GUI settings for it but expect there must be such a thing.

Comment: Personally I would suggest such a feature is a step too far. You'll rue the day when you make a change with having the opportunity to reflect on what you are doing... Even seasoned users make mistakes.

Comment: Albeit I agree with this it's quite annoying when working on files on the fly. I'll often save a file every minute updating text. Typically you're given the option to "always do this" on prompts but this one does not present such an option. If I don't catch the prompt before closing the editor potentially the changes are lost.

Comment: Would you be willing to use a terminal window and do the edits with a text mode editor? Would it work to connect to the remote network directory via ssh?

Comment: Dolphin is a file manager, and AFAIK, it doesn't have a built-in text editor. So I am not sure the description you are giving matches your problem.
@Moff Kalast: You might be better off writing your own question, specifying the version of Ubuntu, etc., instead of adding a bounty on a very old question.

Comment: Possibly useful (albeit old) links:
1) https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=70137
2) https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/tdcqm0/dolphin_overwrite_if_file_is_newer/

Comment: Dolphin comes with services Control > Configure Dolphin… > Services
Maybe someone came across the same problem and fixed it already?